# Zend session_start gives Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

When running a Zend application locally I get Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0, i traced that error to a line $startedCleanly = session_start();

I can't get through it, when I restart the server and reload the page I do not get the error, but on every other reload I get it, I looked into a php/tmp dir too see if there are any files, and as I see they aren't there. I think that session isn't written but when I try just a simple test.php file with session_start(); line, without zend framework, I see that there is a file created in that dir.

I really don't know where to go next.

Comment: Can you try raising the `error_reporting` level to get some more info?

Answer (score 3):

Happens when your destructor or error handler throws an exception. That can happen for multiple reasons depending on your exact setup and method for session storage you're using. For example the session directory is not writeable or does not exist, database is not accessible or fields are invalid, redis does not respond, etc.

So, check your settings and look for something that would prevent saving the session data.

More elaborate description [can be found here](http://www.compdigitec.com/labs/2009/08/02/solving-fatal-error-exception-thrown-without-a-stack-frame-in-unknown-on-line-0/).

Comment: I found that the problem is in session_set_save_handler function which does something and messes session_save(), if I comment out the 


    session_set_save_handler(
                array(&$saveHandler, 'open'),
                array(&$saveHandler, 'close'),
                array(&$saveHandler, 'read'),
                array(&$saveHandler, 'write'),
                array(&$saveHandler, 'destroy'),
                array(&$saveHandler, 'gc')
                );

in Session.php in setSaveHandler function everything works fine.

Comment: why the "&"s? If it'S object, than you don't need that AFAIK

Comment: I don't know why those &, it's in a Zend repository, they did it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but I've just figured out that I was getting "Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0" because my 'modified' and 'lifetime' columns were of type 'timestamp without time zone' when they should have been 'integer' (I'm using Postgres 9 BTW)

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could also be a disk full problem !!!